# Plotting with Matplotlib Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, python-3.4

I want to make a function that takes in a list of grades and classifies each one into five categories :
[0, 60), [60, 70), [70, 80), [80, 90), [90, 100]

And then use matplotlib to make a pie chart and histogram.

I'm unsure where to start with this.

Answer (score 1):

Always start at the [gallery](http://matplotlib.org/gallery.html). There you will find an [example pie chart](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pie_and_polar_charts/pie_demo_features.html) and an [example histogram](http://matplotlib.org/examples/statistics/histogram_demo_features.html).

Answer (score 0):

Start by defining a function.
Let's assume you have the list of grades named x:

```
x = [5, 12, 29, 30, 60, 70, 80, 90, 36, 42, 47, 50, 55, 59, 63, 68, 75, 80, 88, 99, 100]
```

you will define a function, f(x)

```
def f(object):
nullsix = []
sixseven = []
seveneight = []      
eightnine = []
nineten = []
for value in object:
    if value >= 0 and value < 60:
        nullsix.append(value)
    elif value < 70:
        sixseven.append(value)
    elif value < 80:
        seveneight.append(value)
    elif value < 90:
        eightnine.append(value)
    else:
        nineten.append(value)
print(nullsix)
print(sixseven)
print(seveneight)
print(eightnine)
print(nineten)
```

and when you call the function `f(x)`, the result will be:

```
[5, 12, 29, 30, 36, 42, 47, 50, 55, 59]
[60, 63, 68]
[70, 75]
[80, 80, 88]
[90, 99, 100]
```

To make use of matplotlib function, you should import it within the function and define labels, sizes, and if you want to offset a slice or not. Here, try this:

```
def f(object):
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
nullsix = []
sixseven = []
seveneight = []
eightnine = []
nineten = []
for value in object:
    if value >= 0 and value < 60:
        nullsix.append(value)
    elif value < 70:
        sixseven.append(value)
    elif value < 80:
        seveneight.append(value)
    elif value < 90:
        eightnine.append(value)
    else:
        nineten.append(value)
a = int(len(nullsix))
b = int(len(sixseven))
c = int(len(seveneight))
d = int(len(eightnine))
e = int(len(nineten))
labels = '90-100', '80-90', '70-80', '60-70', '0-60'
sizes = [e, b, c, d, a]
colors = ['yellowgreen', 'gold', 'lightskyblue', 'lightcoral', 'orange']
explode = (0.1, 0, 0, 0, 0)
plt.pie(sizes, explode=explode, labels=labels, colors=colors,
    autopct='%1.1f%%', shadow=True, startangle=90)
plt.axis('equal')
plt.show()
```

Tell me if it works, I don't have matplotlib installed, just followed the demo.